# Restriction in xsd with complicated regex

Tags: java, regex, xsd, xsd-validation

I got xsd file and it validates field by regex. However, I don't know which value will be matched with this regex. Can anyone help to analyze it?

```
([A-Za-z0-9]|[+|\?|/|\-|:|\(|\)|\.|,|&apos;|\p{Zs}])*
```

I tried with this text `exp-Vilian-20180726143039` and it matched. However the requirement needs underscore( _ ) instead of hyphen ( - )

Thank so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expressions allows strings

- A-Z and a-z as well as 0-9 (`[A-Za-z0-9]`)
- `+`, `?`, `/`, `-`, `:`, `(`, `)`, `.`, `,`, `&apos;` or any whitespace, with zero width (`[+|\?|/|\-|:|\(|\)|\.|,|&apos;|\p{Zs}]`)
- of any length including 0 (`*`)

So no underscores allowed.